# Headphone Controls Android

Tags: applications, root-access, headphones, nexus-6

Most threads I find on this information is pretty old, so I wanted to see if anyone has come up with a workaround.

My headphones are the RHA SA950i (wired), which are wonderful. However, the headphone controls (Volume Up, Pause/Skip, Volume Down) only slightly work. The center button, Pause/Skip works, but Volume Up/Down do not. I have a Google Nexus 6. I was wondering if there have been any apps or other workarounds created that allows for me to use Volume Up/Down? Also, I do have a custom ROM (OmniROM) with Root access.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes custom rom's have issues with Bluetooth, contact the maintainers of this rom and maybe check if other people have problems.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned these are wired headsets.